# How to pass token and refresh token as Authorization in the header using OpenApi 2.O?

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, insomnia

I'm new to OpenApi, I'm using Insomnia and I'm trying to pass Authorization: { "token": "dehxsasn8478snsajsx", "refreshToken": "cddjnc5156" } in the header but Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type, and Authorization are not allowed so I have to use a security scheme for that purpose but which security scheme should I go for and how to pass this structure(Authorization: { "token": "dehxsasn8478snsajsx", "refreshToken": "cddjnc5156" }) in the header is what's driving me crazy. Here's what I'm trying ..I know it's wrong but i'm stuck

```
securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
        type: apiKey
        in: header
        name: Authorization
        content:
           application/json:
             schema:
               type: object
               properties:
                 token:
                   type: string
                   example: "ab"
                 refreshToken:
                   type: string
                   example: "djdjsn"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use apiKey as security schema

```
securitySchemes:
    apiKey:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: Authorization
```

and in the path add

```
security:
        - apiKey: []
```

and in the header pass

```
{ "token": "dehxsasn8478snsajsx", "refreshToken": "cddjnc5156" }
```

as the string.